# Showing "Runaway Argument?" error

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations

```
\documentclass[25pt]{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{animateinline}[loop, controls]{4}

\newcounter{x}
\setcounter{x}{0}

\whiledo{\arabic{x} < 1.7}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymax = 10, ymin = -1, title = Parallelogram Law]

\addplot[color = red, thick, domain = 0 : pi/2, samples=9]{(0,0)--(cos(deg(x)),sin(deg(x))};
\addplot[]{(0,0)--(2,0)};
\addplot[]{(2,0)--(2+cos(deg(x)),sin(deg(x))};
\addplot[]{(cos(deg(x)),sin(deg(x))--(2+cos(deg(x)),sin(deg(x))};
\addplot[]{(0,0)--(2+cos(deg(x)),sin(deg(x))};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{animateinline}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. It would be nice if you would put your question at the body of the question, rather than only at its title.

Comment: `whiledo` has no body, and you can't do floating-point comparisons in that way. Also, you never increment `x`.  Why don't you use `\multiframe`?